# How do I run Selenium IDE scripts in Selenium RC?

Tags: javascript, html, vb.net, selenium

I am new to using the selenium testing tool and would like to know how to run selenium IDE scripts in selenium RC.  I need examples and screenshots please

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, to run the selenium IDE scripts in RC you have to export them into a particular language (Java, C#, Python). After that, you need to run a RC Server and a RC Client that will send requests to this server.

The first place I would go to get started is this documentation:
http://seleniumhq.org/docs/05_selenium_rc.html